# $post_id or $post->ID in wordpress meta box construction

Tags: wordpress, meta

Can someone explain why when creating meta boxes the callback needs the post id to be passed via $post->ID, however with the action hook 'save_post', the function can pass $post_id.  A general explanation of when to use which one would help clear up some issues I've been having, thanks.

ex:

```
function show_custom_meta_box($post) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_meta_class', true); 
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // Begin the field table and loop
    echo '<table class="form-table">';

        echo '<tr>
                <th><label for="custom-meta-class">Custom Meta Box</label></th>
                <td>
                <input class="widefat" type="text" name="custom-meta-class" id="custom-meta-class" value="'.$meta.'" size="50" />';

        echo '</td></tr>';

    echo '</table>'; // end table
}
```

and for the $post_id

```
function save_custom_meta($post) {

    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
    if ( !isset( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post_id;
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
    /* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
    if ( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
    /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['custom-meta-class'] ) ? sanitize_html_class( $_POST['custom-meta-class'] ) : '' );
    /* Get the meta key. */
    $meta_key = 'custom_meta_class';
    /* Get the meta value of the custom field key. */
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );

    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value )
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value, true );

    /* If the new meta value does not match the old value, update it. */
    elseif ( $new_meta_value && $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );

    /* If there is no new meta value but an old value exists, delete it. */
    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but I have the exact same problem.  I'm surprised nobody has chimed in in the last 7 years.

Here's my code, it works (in functions.php)

```
add_action('save_post','extract_citations',100,1);
function extract_citations($post_id){
$the_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $the_post->post_content;
preg_match_all('/<a\s+.*?href=[\"\']?([^\"\' >]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i',$content,$citation_array);
$citation_urls = $citation_array[1];
update_post_meta($post_id,'citations',serialize($citation_urls));
}
```

Here is code that does NOT work, despite being theoretically correct:

```
add_action('save_post','extract_citations',100,1);
function extract_citations($post){
$the_post = get_post($post->ID);
$content = $the_post->post_content;
preg_match_all('/<a\s+.*?href=[\"\']?([^\"\' >]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i',$content,$citation_array);
$citation_urls = $citation_array[1];
update_post_meta($post->ID,'citations',serialize($citation_urls));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread, but I wanted to add my thoughts.
Let’s pretend that the Post ID is 1724

In the first example you are inserting 1724 directly into the function so line 3 would become

```
$the_post = get_post(1724);
```

While in the second example of are asking for the ID of the post number so your line 3 would become

```
$the_post = get_post(1703->ID);
```

The thing to remember is that when you call the function within your site the number is added which becomes $post_id, it doesn’t actually matter what word you put in the brackets of the function.